# Column - Most frequent letter in a group of 4 rows

Tags: matlab

I have this column in excel;

```
V
V
F
V
C
F
F
F
...
```

Now I'm reading it with matlab using

```
[~,txt] = xlsread('2012_15min.xls','JAN','B25:B2999');
```

And now I want to get a new column that gives me the most repetitive letter in groups of 4 rows, so for the first 4 rows I will get `V` (in this example), and for the second `F`.

So I will get a new column with;

```
V
F
...
```

I hope you can help me.

Comment: Is Excel the only tool you're using?  Is `xlsread` a VBA function?  Or are you using Matlab?  Which really changes the nature of your question.  Please be specific in how you ask.

Comment: The column of data is in excel and I'm using matlab to work with that data-

Comment: what did you try already?

Comment: I tried mode but I didn't get anything, I also tried what Shai said buy I'm getting an error, I should also say that I have some chars in this column with more than one letter like AB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the command `mode` to find the most frequent occurence. The only cavity is that `mode` does not work with `chars`. So, you can `reshape` `txt` to be of size `4`-by-whatever and then find the `mode` of each 4-column

```
>> res = char( mode( double( reshape( txt, 4, [] ) ) ) ).'
res =
V
F
```

Comment: Thx for answering but I'm getting this error ;

??? Error using ==> mode at 57
X must be an array of double or single
numeric values.


Error in ==> Untitled at 27
res = char( mode( reshape( txt,
4, [] ) ) )


I have some periods of data that is like AB I don't know if this makes any diferrence

Comment: @user3103689 please copy Shai's answer **exactly** you'll see a cast to `double` before `mode` is applied: this cast will resolve the error you get.

Comment: Still not working, same error 

??? Error using ==> double
Conversion to double from cell is not possible.

Error in ==> Untitled at 20
res = char( mode( double( reshape( txt, 4, [] )
) ) )

Comment: I don't know if this is useful but I'm using Matlab R2009b, and sometimes I will find rows of 2 letters ex: SV.